# how to convert image raw data to image

Tags: node.js, spring-boot

I want to show user's document file which is return by spring boot api in nodejs
but the file is not showing.

> Here is my code of spring boot api

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + storeDocName + "");
httpServletResponse.setContentType(fileType);
httpServletResponse.setContentLengthLong(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()).length);
httpServletResponse.getOutputStream().write(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
```

> Here is my node js code

```
requestMethodGetForImageData: function(url, form, header) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        //SET ALL THESE PARATMETER TO MAKE REQUEST
        request.get({ url: url, qs: form, headers: header }, function(error, response, body) {
            var result = {
              body: response.body,
              header: response.headers['content-type']
            };
            resolve(result);
          }
        });

    });
},
```

> I am using request module of nodejs to send the request to spring api and in nodejs here, I am calling this request function

```
router.get("/loadStoreDocument", function(req, res) {

  var url = httpProtocol + httpServer + servicePort + serviceUrl;

  //SET HEADER
  headers = {
    'Authorization': "token"
  };

  //SET FORM DATA
  form = {
    account_id: "id",
    token_type: "token_type",
    document_child_id: "id"
  };
  requestHandling.requestMethodGetForImageData(url, form, headers)
    .then((result) => {
      res.header("content-type", result.header);
      res.send(result.body);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("ERROR IN GET STORE PROFILE");
      console.log(err);
      res.send(err);
    });
});
```

> But when I call this URL(loadStoreDocument) then it returns image like this
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJbzB.png)
>
> Response of spring api is here(image data)
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc7ge.png)
>
> Please help me, I search this everywhere but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: What is the expected output from node.js api call? Is it https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc7ge.png or https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJbzB.png ?

Comment: @explorer my expected output is actual image

Comment: @explorer but if the result is receive like this then i am also want to know that how to process on that response

Comment: question mentions that the expected output image is https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc7ge.png. Please update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `encoding: null` in `request.get()` options.

```js
request.get({ url: url, qs: form, headers: header, encoding: null })
```

From `request` [docs](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/README.md#requestoptions-callback):

> encoding - encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If
>   null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the
>   default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter
>   to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). (Note: if
>   you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null.)

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer, I also found the same answer that you put, I have already solved my problem by doing this. so, your answer is correct according to me and I accept this answer.